# ESP32 High Sample Rate I2S

Tags: audio, embedded, esp32, i2s

Recently, I've been working on a project that involves receiving a high sample rate I2S signal and writing it to an SD card with an ESP32. At the moment, however, I believe I'm struggling to even receive the I2S signal correctly. I believe I'm missing bits and samples.

My I2S signal uses a 325 kHz word select clock and a 10.4 MHz bit clock to send samples at 325000 samples/sec at 16 bits/sample. This is a lot higher than typical audio, but according to the [ESP32 datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf#i2s) it should be capable of bit clocks up to 40 MHz. I'm also using an external I2S clock, so this is running as a "slave device". The bitrate of this is 1300000 which I got with this formula: `[sample rate (325000)] * [channels (2)] * [bytes per sample (2)]`.

I wrote [this benchmark program](https://gist.github.com/Roman-Port/f782be7f0ba8cae2ea42ac4e958fb1eb) to do nothing but stream I2S samples in and benchmark the actual received speed to compare to what it should be. I have to use the APLL feature as the driver complains that the sample rate is too high if I don't. I calculate the mclk frequency using the formula `[sample rate (325000)] * [bits per sample (16)] * [multiplier (8)]`. Upon running the program, it claims that the data rate it is receiving is `1150678 bytes/sec` which is 88% of the expected data speed. This means that samples are being dropped.

Additionally, as a test, I connected the word select line to the data line and recorded using the ESP32. The clock is generated by the device I have the ESP32 attached to. This should make every other sample go 0xFFFF to 0x0000 as the word select is pulled high or low every other 2-byte sample. However, examining the data below, it appears bits are *very often* incorrectly flipped as each 2-byte sample is received. I believe this is why all of the high sample rate audio I've tried has appeared corrupted.

[image: corruption in the bits that should be going from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF and back]

For reference, here's what the two clock lines look like on a scope. The bit clock is in green, and the word select is in yellow. The data line matches is the same as the word select, in yellow, in the test above.

[image: scope showing 16 bits-per-sample I2S signal]

As a sort of sanity check, I also tried this program on a lower sample rate signal at 44100 samples/sec at 32 bits/sample. Aside from changing the sample rate, bits/sample, and recalculating the mclk, all other settings remained the same. Running this program reported that samples were still being dropped. However, increasing the multiplier used in the mclk formula from 8 to 128 resolved the problem and samples were received at 99.9% the expected data rate, which is within margin of error. No bits were being incorrectly read either.

This leads me to believe that the culprit is that mclk multiplier. However, setting mclk equal to or greater than ~83200000 **causes the entire ESP32 to hang** when calling `i2s_driver_install`. 8 is the maximum multiple-of-two multiplier I can use without hitting that limit and hanging the ESP32.

What am I missing? I assume that the mclk needs to be higher, but I can't seem to increase it beyond 83.2 MHz. I'm hardly at 1/4th the maximum bit clock speed the manual claims to support anyways.

Thanks!

Comment: Like all datasheets - you need to read the fine print. In this case there is the 8 times   requirement for the internal clock for externally clocked I2S (same for SPI) which limits the slave I2S bitrate spec. BTW your scope waveforms are garbage. Have you got the probes grounded correctly?

Comment: @Kartman Thanks for the reply. I had no idea that there was that requirement, I'm sorry. Is there a different microprocessor I should look at instead? Or does hardware perhaps exist that allows me to just shove a parallel data stream onto an SD card? Thanks!